# Drupal 8 how to pass a value to menu twig template

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal, I want to pass domain URL to use in `menu.html.twig` template. How can I do this. Actually I have a menu of 5 domains all pointing to the same Drupal instance. Based on the domain name I want to make the menu active.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending of Artreaktors answer since the OP isn't too familiar with Drupal.

Create a module with any name you want. If you need help with this take a look at [Drupal Console](https://drupalconsole.com/), it will help you a bunch.

Inside the folder of your module you will find a module_name.module file.

Here you will add the code given by Artreaktor:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_menu(&$vars) {
  $domain = \Drupal::service('domain.negotiator')->getActiveDomain();
  $vars['domain'] = $domain->getUrl();
}
```

mymodule here stands for the name of your module. Don't forget to enable your module and clearing the cache!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in hook_preprocess_hook(&$vars).

```
function mymodule_preprocess_menu(&$vars) {
  $domain = \Drupal::service('domain.negotiator')->getActiveDomain();
  $vars['domain'] = $domain->getUrl();
}
```

Now you can use {{ domain }} variable in your twig.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your support. I am new to Drupal code.. Can I add this function in my theme.inc file....?

Comment: Use this code either in your custom theme (mytheme.theme) or in your module (mymodule.module) file. You should replace "mymodule" with the real name of your theme or module.